# Hive like does not work when the string is from other table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, sql-like

I meet a strange problem in hive

The table `a`:

```
id, domain
1,  m.taobao.com
2,  m.tmall.com
```

The table b

```
domain
%taobao\\.com%
%tmall\\.com%
```

When I use:

```
Select a.id, a.domain from a where a like '%taobao\\.com%' or a.like '%tmall\\.com%'
```

It works well

But when I use

```
select a.id, a.domain from a, b where a.domain like b.domain
```

I got return null.

The `b.domain` is `'%taobao\\.com%'` or `'%tmall\\.com%'`. What's the different using them direct in SQL query? What makes the second query failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `'\\'` in the template it works fine:

```
select a.*
from
(--Use your table instead of this subquery
  select stack(2,
              1,  'm.taobao.com',
              2,  'm.tmall.com') as (id, domain)
)a
cross join 
(--Use your table instead of this subquery
 select stack(2,
              '%taobao.com%',
              '%tmall.com%'
              ) as domain
) b
where a.domain like b.domain;
```

Result:

```
OK
1       m.taobao.com
2       m.tmall.com
```

And the same with constant template. This does not produce rows:

```
select a.*
from
(--Use your table instead of this subquery
  select stack(2,
              1,  'm.taobao.com',
              2,  'm.tmall.com') as (id, domain)
)a
where a.domain like '%taobao\\.com%'
```

And this works fine:

```
where a.domain like '%taobao.com%'
```

[Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) says that `LIKE` operator recognizes only `_` and `%` templates: "The _ character in B matches any character in A (similar to . in posix regular expressions) while the % character in B matches an arbitrary number of characters in A (similar to .* in posix regular expressions). For example, 'foobar' like 'foo' evaluates to FALSE whereas 'foobar' like 'foo_ _ _' evaluates to TRUE and so does 'foobar' like 'foo%'." So, you do not need to escape `'.'` for LIKE operator.

You need to escape `'.'` to match dot character it only for `RLIKE` operator because it uses  Java regular expression.